# .NET Core WebAPI dependency injection resolve null

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, .net-core

I use .NET Core WebAPI with dependency injection and multiple authentication schemas (http basic, access keys, JWT). I inject some business services which require some authenticated user data. If user is authenticated by any of auth middleware, DI works fine. If the user is not authenticated, DI cannot resolve some services. I need DI to return `null`.

How is that possible? Code bellow will result in exception, `null` is not allowed as result.

```
services.AddTransient<IMasterRepository>(serviceProvider =>
        {
            var _serviceFactory = new RepositoriesFactory(Configuration);

            if (!Authenticated)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return _serviceFactory.CreateMasterRepository();
        });
```

Also, I cannot return 401 in auth middleware, because another middleware may success (expl: cannot return 401 in http basic auth middleware because next one, JWT, may success)

Also, I cannot add "authentication required" check after all auth middlewares because some controllers are public (no authentication / dependency injection required).

Any advice?
Thanks!

Comment: Does it work when explicitly stating the generic type as nullable using `?` (C# 8)?

Answer (score 7):

There's no problem in *registering* an implementation as `null`.  It's only in *resolving* that you will have a problem.

In other words, if you register:

```
services.AddTransient<IMasterRepository>(provider => null);
```

And then try:

```
private readonly IMasterRepository _repository;

public SomeController(IMasterRepository repository)
{
    _repository = repository;
}
```

You will get an `InvalidOperationException` at runtime, with a message similar to:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'MyApp.IMasterRepository' while attempting to activate 'MyApp.Controllers.SomeController'

**However,** there is a simple workaround.  Rather than injecting the interface, inject an `IEnumerable` of that interface:

```
private readonly IMasterRepository _repository;

public SomeController(IEnumerable<IMasterRepository> repositories)
{
    _repository = repositories.First();  // (using System.Linq)
}
```

You might think it should be `FirstOrDefault`, however there will indeed be a single item containing the `null` you registered.

This approach works because DI in ASP.Net Core supports registering multiple implementations of a given type and doesn't distinguish between `null` and object instances at time of registration.

Do keep in mind that even though this works, it's not recommended because now the `_repository` variable is potentially nullable, and a null check must be used every time it is accessed.  For example: `if (_repository != null) { _repository.DoSomething(); }` or `_repository?.DoSomething();`.  Most people do not expect to write code like that.

This covers the DI part of the question.  But if indeed the issue is strictly with auth then [ste-fu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59564253/634824) describes a more appropriate approach.

Comment: I can't watch this :o, if I see this in a code-base, I'd stop whatever I was doing and refactor this out.

Comment: @huysentruitw - Indeed. I added a paragraph to echo that this is not a recommended practice.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The default DI framework does not allow for the factory delegate to return null by design.

Consider [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) by creating a NullObject derived from the interface

```
public class NullRepository : IMasterRepository {
    public static readonly IMasterRepository Empty = new NullRepository();

    public NullRepository () { }

    //...implement members that do nothing and may return empty collections.
}
```

that does nothing when invoked.

```
services.AddTransient<IMasterRepository>(serviceProvider => {
    IMasterRepository result = NullRepository.Empty;
    var _serviceFactory = new RepositoriesFactory(Configuration);
    if (Authenticated) {
        result = _serviceFactory.CreateMasterRepository();
    }
    return result;
});
```

Checking for null now becomes

```
//ctor
public SomeClass(IMasterRepository repository) {

    if(repository == NullRepository.Empty)
        //...throw

    //...
}
```

Comment: Null Object pattern addresses the problem. However, the patterns is implemented in this answer incorrectly. `SomeClass` should not know with which interface implementation it's working - that's the principle of interfaces that the user of the interface does not check what's behind it.

Answer (score 3):

To my mind, this sounds like a problem with your dependency setup.

All your auth Middleware should be setting the `ClaimsPrincipal` on the `HttpContext` as part of the `Invoke` method if the authentication is successful.

Whilst a service may need to be able to access the `ClaimsPrincipal` in order to function correctly, you can do this by injecting [`IHttpContextAccessor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1) in the constructor and enabling it in the `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs`.

Getting the DI container to return null would just mean that you have to make lots of null checks all over your code. Ensuring that the `ClaimsPrincipal` is correctly set means that you can leverage the `[Authorize]` attribute to control access to particular Controllers or methods or setup [Policy-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1) which should return the correct status codes after all the auth middleware has run.

Answer (score 2):

While you could create a wrapper class that is able to hold the service instance or `null` -OR- you could inject a dummy service in case the user is not authenticated, it's not recommended from a clean-code perspective. Both solutions would be a code smell as for the first: you would have to place null checks everywhere, even in places where you'd expect the service. And the latter: it seems like the code could actually use the service, but it's not clear a dummy service will be provided.

To keep your code clean, I'd just move the public routes, that are not requiring those services, to a separate controller class (with the same route as they have now) that does not depend on the service. This way, you can just register the repository as-is and avoid magic trickery.